# How to write a bash script to merge several file into one

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am using the Linux system. I would like to write a script to do these things below.

I have few folders named Folder 1, Folder 2, Folder 3 ...Folder 100 saved in test.In each folder I have a file named file.txt. How can I write a script to merge the files together. I type one script by myself,

```
for 
   file.txt in ~/test

do 
   cat $file.txt >> test.txt

done
```

However it shows that file.txt not a valid identifier due to it is in test/Folder 1.

Is that possible I can fix the code.

Many thanks

Comment: Does it have to be a script? Otherwise, just use a command similar to **cat test/Folder*/file.txt > test.txt**

Comment: Hi Thomas, brilliant! It worked. Such a easy way! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the find command as shown below

```
find ~/test -name "file.txt" -exec cat {} \; >> test.txt
```

Doing this will `search/find` recursively in `~/test` finding everything called `file.txt` and perform the `cat` command on everything it finds in the `{}` array finally outputting all of the files contents into `file.txt`